# Wordpress - URL directory parameter without redirect

Tags: wordpress, plugins, parameters, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I've created a wordpress plugin that uses a shortcode in combination with an URL parameter to load a certain text.

The default page is:

```
   domainname.com/test

   [shortcode for plugin]

... default template ...
```

It can load some text using these parameters:

```
domainname.com/test?book_id=BWBR0002656&art_id=1

       [shortcode for plugin]

... loaded the text for the book_id and art_id ...
```

I'd like to change the javascript parameter url from the current **domainname.com/test?book_id=BWBR0002656&art_id=1** to **domainname.com/test/BWBR0002656/1** without triggering a wordpress 404 redirect.

Is this possible to do with the shortcode page still functioning ?

Comment: What does the shortcode do? Can you post the code for the shortcode? What does JavaScript have to do with the URL? Do you have any custom post types registered with the URL slugs of book_id or art_id?

Comment: the shortcode actualle has nothing to do with the URL, it just loads the javascript files.

The javascript loads a certain book and article from the plugin directory (they are just html files with content, no php involved).


I know how to change the javascript working from ?book_id to /<book_id>/<article> , but I'm stuck on the 404 redirect part. It has to work with .htaccess?

Comment: You can change .htaccess manually but the WordPress way is to use the [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API). If you don't, you run the risk of breaking lots of other stuff on the WP installation. Much better would be to write a plugin with a custom post type that uses the `/test/` slug and a rewrite endpoint for your article. This can be done by rewriting the query as well but that definitely requires more work. You may get away with some creative use of something like [Advanced Custom Post Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/).

Comment: I'd rather code it then creatively using some plugin that might not suit all my needs

Comment: I'll write you an outline... do you want `/test` to be a single page or will there be more "thing" like `/test` that are similar?

Comment: I managed to get it working; see below for my answer (its too long for a comment). Thanks for your time and for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working using this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' );
function wpa5413_init()
{
    // Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
    add_rewrite_rule(
        // The regex to match the incoming URL
        'test/([^/]+)',
        // The resulting internal URL: `index.php` because we still use WordPress
        // `pagename` because we use this WordPress page

        'index.php?pagename=test',
        // This is a rather specific URL, so we add it to the top of the list
        // Otherwise, the "catch-all" rules at the bottom (for pages and attachments) will "win"
        'top' );
}
```

it will load the /test/ page with the args, and the javascript will handle the rest.

Everything after /test/ is accepted without an 404 error. Even: /test/a/b/c/d/e